# How to access a Org Level Custom Setting in a Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, visual-flows

How can I read a custom setting in Salesforce Flow. I have created a Org level Custom Setting called FeatureFlag__c with only one boolean field IsActive__c.
The idea is, of the org level IsActive__c is true, run the flow else show a screen with some default message.
In the flow, I have created a SObjectVariable by the name "SetFieldFeatureFlagFromCustomSetting" and reading it in the very first step of type assignment as "{!SetFieldFeatureFlagFromCustomSetting.IsActive__c"

[image: Assign the SObjectVariable to a Local variable inside a flow]

It is always coming up as null. Is should be true as the org level custom setting is set to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You created an SObject variable. This isn't what you needed. Instead, go to the Resources tab on the left palette, create a new Formula, and use the appropriate formula you're looking for (e.g. `$Setup.SetFieldFeatureFlagFromCustomSetting__c.IsActive__c`). Then, in your assignment area, reference the formula:

```
{!VariableNameToSet} equals {!FormulaNameForCustomSetting}
```

Or, you can use that formula directly as a criteria in a Choice. The other variable isn't necessary in this case.

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm. Thank you very much @sfdcfox